# Plotting datapoints found in data given in a .txt file

Tags: plotting, import

Well, my question is the following: I have a `.txt` file that consists of the following data:

```
r&=3&a&=3&b&=4&c&=10\\
r&=3&a&=8&b&=15&c&=120\\
r&=3&a&=20&b&=55&c&=1540\\
r&=4&a&=34&b&=119&c&=7140\\
r&=5&a&=24&b&=70&c&=4900\\
r&=5&a&=11&b&=22&c&=946\\
r&=9&a&=10&b&=19&c&=1045\\
r&=10&a&=18&b&=45&c&=5985\\
r&=10&a&=49785&b&=6413415&c&=123395663059845\\
r&=13&a&=91839&b&=16068720&c&=774611255177760\\
...
...
...
```

Now, I want to use Mathematica to make a `ListPlot[]` of my data with the points $(r,a)$.

Let's give an example. In order to input my file I can use:

```
In[1]:=Import["name of the file.txt", "Data"]

Out[1]={{r&=3&a&=3&b&=4&c&=10\\},{r&=3&a&=8&b&=15&c&=120\\},
{r&=3&a&=20&b&=55&c&=1540\\},{r&=4&a&=34&b&=119&c&=7140\\},
{r&=5&a&=24&b&=70&c&=4900\\},{r&=5&a&=11&b&=22&c&=946\\},
{r&=9&a&=10&b&=19&c&=1045\\},{r&=10&a&=18&b&=45&c&=5985\\}
```

Now, I want Mathematica to plot the following points (using `ListPlot[]`):

$$(3,3),(3,8),(3,20),(4,34),(5,24),(5,11),(9,10),(10,18)$$

> In reality my data is way bigger. But this small example demonstrates the code I am looking for. Thank you so so much for your help and time.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

First, import the string. In your case it'll just be `Import["name of the file.txt", "Data"]`

```
s = ImportString["r&=3&a&=3&b&=4&c&=10\\\\
r&=3&a&=8&b&=15&c&=120\\\\
r&=3&a&=20&b&=55&c&=1540\\\\
r&=4&a&=34&b&=119&c&=7140\\\\
r&=5&a&=24&b&=70&c&=4900\\\\
r&=5&a&=11&b&=22&c&=946\\\\
r&=9&a&=10&b&=19&c&=1045\\\\
r&=10&a&=18&b&=45&c&=5985\\\\
r&=10&a&=49785&b&=6413415&c&=123395663059845\\\\
r&=13&a&=91839&b&=16068720&c&=774611255177760\\\\"]
```

Now, the magic. We `Flatten` the resulting list of strings, and then get all of the digits from each string (using `StringCases[DigitCharacter..]`). We then convert the resulting strings of digits into numbers using `ToExpression`.

```
nums = ToExpression@StringCases[Flatten@s, DigitCharacter ..]
```

Now we have our numbers:

```
{{3, 3, 4, 10}, {3, 8, 15, 120}, {3, 20, 55, 1540}, {4, 34, 119, 
  7140}, {5, 24, 70, 4900}, {5, 11, 22, 946}, {9, 10, 19, 1045}, {10, 
  18, 45, 5985}, {10, 49785, 6413415, 123395663059845}, {13, 91839, 
  16068720, 774611255177760}}
```

And now we simply plot the first two numbers from each sublist:

```
ListPlot[nums[[All, 1 ;; 2]]]
```

[image]

Answer (score 6):

Just for completeness: it is also possible to do all this with just using options for `Import`:

```
data=Import[fname, {"Table", "Data", All, {2, 4}},"FieldSeparators"->{"=", "&", "\\\\"}]
```

see the documentation for the "Table" format for details:

http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/format/Table.html

Comment: Didn't occur to me, very nice.

Comment: I think it is a longstanding weakness that the documentation of the import functionality is not easy to find and missing many details. That was patially the motivation for giving this answer. If you know that there is a lot more there than is obvious will hopefully make some search the documentation more closely...

Answer (score 3):

```
Import["path to txt"] // 
   StringSplit[#, {"\\\\"}] & // 
  Map[StringSplit[#, {"&=", "&"}] &] // #[[All, {2, 4}]] & // ToExpression // ListPlot
```

[image]